# Is it possible to configure the PHP interpreter so that $ _GET is populated from command line arguments?

Tags: php, server, cgi

I am writing my cgi for training purposes and trying to figure out how to fill out $ _GET. Is it possible to configure the PHP interpreter so that $ _GET is populated from command line arguments (without using a browser and server)? It may be possible to write something in the configuration so that the php interpreter itself populates the $ _GET array. Unfortunately, I could not find anything about this (operating system - linux).

Comment: What's wrong with using `argv` ?

Comment: [`auto_prepend_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) for defining a custom $_GET population scheme.